# Moq: Setup a mocked method to fail on the first call, succeed on the second

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq

What's the most succinct way to use Moq to mock a method that will throw an exception the first time it is called, then succeed the second time it is called?

Comment: Moq 4.2 & higher now supports this via `SetupSequence()`.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I would make use of `Callback` and increment a counter to determine whether or not to throw an exception from `Callback`.

```
[Test]
public void TestMe()
{
    var count = 0;
    var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
    mock.Setup(a => a.MyMethod()).Callback(() =>
        {
            count++;
            if(count == 1)
                throw new ApplicationException();
        });
    Assert.Throws(typeof(ApplicationException), () => mock.Object.MyMethod());
    Assert.DoesNotThrow(() => mock.Object.MyMethod());
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    void MyMethod();
}
```

Comment: this is a good answer and this approach becomes preferable once you want more than 2 things to happen.

Comment: This approach is simple which is nice, but check that post by Phil Haack from @Mathias' answer. It's pretty slick. Using an extension method you can do something like `reader.Setup(r => r.Read()).ReturnsInOrder(true, true, false);`

Comment: ReturnsInOrder() is nice if you want to return a sequence of values but it wasn't readily apparent how to use it to throw an exception as part of the sequence.

Comment: This answer is not wrong, but using `SetupSequence` is easier and more elegant for sure. Check @aghidini's answer.

Answer (score 66):

Starting with Moq 4.2 you can just use the built-in method `SetupSequence()` (as stated by @RichardBarnett comment).

Example:

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>();
mock.SetupSequence(x => x.MyMethod("param1"))
    .Throws<MyException>()
    .Returns("test return");
```

Comment: This only works if `MyMethod` has a return type. If the method is `void` then you can't use this approach. Would be nice if there were a way to do this with `void` methods

Answer (score 18):

The best that I've come up with so far is this:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

[Test]
public void TestBarExceptionThenSuccess()
{
    var repository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Default);
    var mock = repository.Create<IFoo>();

    mock.Setup(m => m.Bar()).
        Callback(() => mock.Setup(m => m.Bar())). // Setup() replaces the initial one
        Throws<Exception>();                      // throw an exception the first time

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 That's a cool approach. Just might not be clear to someone stumbling into the code what's going on there.

Comment: Nice one, I didnt think of this!

Comment: Note that replacing the mock wipes out the history so you can't do `mock.Verify(m => m.Bar(), Times.Exactly(2))`.

Answer (score 7):

Phil Haack has an interesting [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/29/moq-sequences.aspx) on setting up a method to return a particular sequence of results. It seems that it would be a good starting point, with some work involved, because instead of a sequence of values of a certain type, you would need now to have a sequence of results which could be of type T, or an exception.